# How to login in MyAdmin yahoo server

Tags: phpmyadmin, yahoo

I have an account in yahoo and I just installed phpMyAdmin and when I try to login it got stuck, I have tried the default  **Username : root and password : I leave it empty** and it says the password or username are wrong.

Yahoo doesn't have any kind of support on this. How can I access the phpMyAdmin Panel Control.

Comment: please explain more about your account type .

Comment: OnlyMAJ, its a business account, and i found the option to install MyAdmin in the yahoo server, but there is not any information regarding the login username and password.

Answer (score 0):

phpmyadmin uses mysql users for its login. So you need to go through your mysql users information there to login into your phpmyadmin area.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the way to solve this problem, i figure it out the way to have access to the file config.inc.php in the admin folder , and in the section

```html
/* User used to manipulate with storage */
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = '**********'; 
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '***************';
```

i found the user name and password, now i can create my databases and tables directly from de Myadmin Panel Control in yahoo server.

yahoo is ugly... now thinking to move to 1and1.com.